# Funcionamiento interno list View

Tags: java, android-studio

seré breve, estoy dando android studio en el segundo curso de DAM, concretamente estamos dando en estos momentos los listviews. Dicho esto tengo una pregunta, como dibuja la aplicación los elementos que conforman la lista en pantalla???Conozco el funcionamiento de todo el proceso, incluyendo la creacion de un adaptador personalizado para la lista. Entiendo que la lista a nivel interno y desde otro método llama al metodo getView() del adaptador, el cual le retorna la vista a dibujar. A partir de aquí como se dibuja la lista? cual es el proceso que se da una vez se ha invocado a getView ()???
La pregunta es por mera curiosidad y para tener una mejor comprensión del proceso.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ]Bievenido , agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.